# Add link parameter to asp tag helpers with pound sign (#) anchor url in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, anchor, html-helper

I have the following url `http://localhost:5000/Home/Index/#test` and I need to pass the `#test` to the action. I used `asp-route="#test"`and `asp-route-id="#test"` but they does not work.

This is my action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing)

```
[Route("Home/Index/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string id)
```

Use tag helpers like

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="#test">Index</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hash or fragment portion of the URL is not part of the route. It only has meaning client-side. I don't think there's any way to add it via the tag helper. Instead you'll need to use something like `Url.Action`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#test">My Link</a>
```

Comment: The action parameter id is null :-(

Comment: @Dino You could use [`asp-fragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-fragment) for generating the URL but ultimately the value in the fragment isn’t going to be sent to the server when the URL itself is followed - that’s just how it is.