# Adding #section in my url in ASP .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't find a question similar to mine or I don't know the exact keywords to search for. I'm trying to get a link to look like this:

> https://localhost/Index#about

however, i'm not sure where to insert the #about in the url parameters.

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">About</a>
```

If you're wondering, I'm using this piece of code for my navbar URLs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok after searching the documentation of Microsoft:

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-fragment="about">About</a>
```

> The asp-fragment attribute defines a URL fragment to append to the
>   URL. The Anchor Tag Helper adds the hash character (#).

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="#about">Index</a>
```

Found this from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804015/9358386)

Comment: Nope, the URL becomes `https://localhost:5001/Home/Index/%23about`

Comment: @DeathKing     <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#test">My Link</a>